# Getting socket ip on socket.io on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I am using socket.io on heroku, and on socket connection I would like to get the client ip,currently I am getting an IP which is not the real IP (I think this is heroku's ip).

I am using socket.manager.handshaken[socket.id].address.address to get the user's ip.. do you have another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`socket.manager.handshaken[socket.id].remoteAddress`

If you need the client port then that would be:
`socket.manager.handshaken[socket.id].remotePort`